# Irreducible components of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I came out with an exercise about reduction of schemes which is not particularly difficult, but I can’t solve it in the most formal way. The exercise asks to find the irreducible components of $X:=\operatorname{Spec(k[x,y,z])}/I$ where $I=(x^2-yz,y^2-xz)$. Now, if think about surfaces as zero loci I find that:

$X=V(x^2-yz,y^2-xz) = V(x^2-yz,y^2-xz)\cup V(x,yz,y^2) = V(x^3-xyz,y^2-xz)\cup V(x,yz,y^2) = V(x^3-y^3,y^2-xz)\cup V(x,yz,y^2) =  V(x-y,y^2-xz)\cup V(x^2+xy+y^2,y^2-xz) \cup V(x,yz,y^2)$

Then notice that:

$V(x-y,y^2-yz) = V(x-y,y) \cup V(x-y,y-z)= V(x,y) \cup V(x-y,y-z)$

$V(x^2+xy+y^2,y^2-xz) = V(x,y)$

$V(x,yz,y^2) = V(x,y)$

To conclude that $X=V(x,y)\cup V(x-y,y-z)$. In doing this I never used the formal definition of $V(…)$ as a scheme, neither think in terms of prime ideals.

1. Is my approach acceptable in the sense that, when possible, it leads to the correct result? Even if it is correct, is there a way to get the result thinking in terms of prime ideals?
2. Thinking about the definitions I see that $V(x,y) \supset V(x^2+xy+y^2) $ because if a prime ideal $p \supset (x,y) \Rightarrow p \supset (x^2 + xy + y^2)$
   But given two ideals $I,J$ it should hold that $V(I) \supset V(J) \Rightarrow I \subset \sqrt{J}$. In particular
   in our case it should hold that $(x,y) \subset (x^2 + xy + y^2)$ but it seems impossible to me: consider the element $x+y$, what polynomial $h$ would satisfy $x+y = h[x^2+xy+y^2]$ ? Where am I wrong? I probably have misunderstood something.

Edit: $k$ denotes an algebraically closed field.

Comment: For 2 you have your inclusion backwards, $V(x, y) \subset V(x^2 + xy + y^2)$.

Comment: For 1, assuming $k$ is algebraically closed and applying the Nullstellensatz, you are looking for a statement along the lines of: if there is a prime ideal $p \supset I$ but $p \not \supset J$ then there is a maximal ideal $m \supset I$ but $m \not \supset J$. If $k$ may not be algebraically closed, consider $I = (x^2 + y^2 + 1)$ and $J = (x^2 + y^2 + 2)$ over $k = \mathbf{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments helped me identify my mistakes. Here's what I concluded:

Regarding point 2, as also pointed out in a comment, it is based on a incorrect assumption or statement. Specifically, $V(x,y) \subset V(x^2+xy+y^2)$ and not vice versa. We observe that $V(x,y) = \{ (x,y), (x,y,z) \}$, while $V(x^2+xy+y^2) = \{ (x,y), (x,y,z), (x^2+xy+y^2) \}$. Therefore, $(x,y) \subset (x^2+xy+y^2)$ as I initially suspected.

Concerning point 1, the zero locus of an ideal $I=(f)$ and $V(f)$, where $f$ is an irreducible polynomial, are related in the following way:

$V(f)= \{ \mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{A}^1_k | f \in \mathbf{p} \} = \{(x-a,y-b)|f(a,b)=0 \} \cup \{(f) \}$

This explains all the steps leading to the final decomposition.

Comment: Warning: Your description for $V(f)$ only makes sense when $k$ is algebraically closed. I assume this is okay though. (consider $V(x^2 + y^2 + 1) \subset \mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$, for example)

Comment: In that case wouldn't it simply be: $V(x^2+y^2+1)=(x^2+y^2+1)$ as  according to my description we would have that $\{ (x-a,y-b) | f(a,b)=0\} = \emptyset $?

Comment: $V(x^2 + y^2 + 1)$ cannot be a singleton, since it is a 1-dimensional subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^2$ by Krull's theorem. Your description misses closed points that are not $\mathbb{R}$-valued. For example, $x^2 + y^2 + 1 \in (x^2 + 1, y)$ but evidently $(x^2 + y^2 + 1) \neq (x^2 + 1, y)$.

Comment: Ok it is clear. Indeed for the text from which I took the exercise it was understood that $k$ denotes an algebraically closed field. I'm adding an explicit edit to my original question.